# In .NET/Link, how do I not open multiple kernels?

Tags: kernel, .netlink

I'm writing an ASP.NET page intended for multiple users.  On the backend we have datatypes that are primarily mathematical, and interact with *Mathematica* for string-to-double evaluations, among others.  We need to make these evaluations up to 100 times per second per user, for up to 100 users, say.  But every time we use NETLink to create a new kernel connection, a new instance of the *Mathematica* kernel opens on the host machine.  10,000 copies of the *Mathematica* kernel on a single machine is obviously undesirable.

If we were guaranteed to have one user, it might work to create a global kernel and use that -- but if we have 100 users, that would create 100 kernels, which is still excessive.  Is there a nice workaround for this?  Perhaps a way to use .NETLink to a kernel that's already opened?

Comment: How about defining kernel as singleton and in the kernel define  context for each user.

Comment: Have you looked at [webMathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/)? It is Java based, so it isn't a perfect fit for your ASP.NET setup, but it has the key feature you seem to need: it provides a queueing system for access to a pool of preinitialized kernels. It is also possible to create webservices which use such a pool of kernels and which your ASP.NET application could use. You even might ask the support at WRI whether it is possible to use only the kernel pool feature from ASP.NET more directly...